# How to check if a string contains only mixed case?

Tags: abap

How could I correct this code line in order to better filter my input conditions :

```
IF STRING CA SY-ABCDE and STRING CN SY-ABCDE.
```

My conditions are :

- Input must not be all UpperCase or all LowerCase (NAME or name) , 'Name' is acceptable.
- Input is acceptable if it contains numbers or symbols (123%Name is acceptable, 123%NAME or 123%name is not).

The code line I provided fulfills the first condition and half of the 2nd, but I can't manage to change it so that it gets denied if input is 123%NAME .

Answer (score 4):

you can also check if there is at least one uppercase letter and one lowercase letter in the string:

```
IF lv_text CA sy-abcde AND lv_text CA to_lower( sy-abcde ) AND lv_text NA '/\[}$*'.
  WRITE:/ 'yes'.
ELSE.
  WRITE:/ 'no'.
ENDIF.
```

Comment: added additional relation for fulfilling the second condition of OP, thus the string can contain any special characters except those he considers erroneous

Answer (score 3):

You can check string with itself uppercase or lowercase format.

```
DATA: lv_m TYPE string VALUE 'Abc',
      lv_l TYPE string,
      lv_u TYPE string.
lv_u = lv_m.
lv_l = lv_m.
TRANSLATE lv_u TO UPPER CASE.
TRANSLATE lv_l TO LOWER CASE.
IF lv_u NE lv_m and lv_u ne lv_m.
  MESSAGE 'Not equal' TYPE 'E'.
ENDIF.
```

Also you can use to_upper / to_lower functions for updated systems.

```
DATA: lv_m TYPE string VALUE 'Abc'.

IF lv_m ne to_upper( lv_m ) and lv_m ne to_lower( lv_m ).
  MESSAGE 'Not equal' TYPE 'E'.
ENDIF.
```

Comment: The answer would benefit of including the handling of both upper case and lower case, and I think it's worth using the functions `to_upper` and `to_lower`.

Comment: I would negate the whole condition (or change it positively to "= or =") so that to send the error only if the input is "NOT acceptable".

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to use a negated `match()` in this case - as it is easier to define what you consider *not* valid for your requirement.

```
REPORT ZZ_TEST_MIXED_CASE.

parameters: string type string lower case.

data(lv_match) = match( val = string regex =
  `^(\U+|\L+)$|[^\w%]`   " <--- Add here after '%' what else you consider as valid 'symbols'
).
if lv_match is initial.
  write: / 'OK'.
else.
  write: / 'Not OK'.
endif.
```